# Web2py logging by importing Python logger

Tags: logging, web2py

I followed the details in the Web2py manual, and setup my logger this way:

I first re-named the config file 'logging.example.conf' to 'logging.conf' in the Web2py root directory, and add 'myapp' to the list of loggers

```
[loggers]
keys=root,rocket,markdown,web2py,rewrite,app,welcome,myapp
```

and add a separate 'logger_myapp' section too

```
[logger_myapp]
level=DEBUG
qualname=web2py.app.myapp
handlers=consoleHandler
propagate=0
```

and then in some model file of myapp, I wrote:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("web2py.app.myapp')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

and somewhere down in the same model file, I tried to test the logging by doing:

```
logger.debug("Check: %s" % details)
```

where `details` is just a variable holding a string

However, when I ran Web2py from the command line, i.e. `python web2py.py`, and when the model file is executed, I see nothing coming out the console.

What did I miss here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `logger.debug("Check: %s" % details)` -- note % instead of $?

Comment: oops, another typo, just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to set the level of handler_consoleHandler to DEBUG. Both the logger and the handler have levels associated with them, and either one can filter your output.

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, just fixed it. thanks for pointing out!

Comment: regarding your second point, isn't that what I've done above?

Comment: That gets me debugging logging! So, just to confirm how things work: the logging level of handler has to be *no higher than* (or equal to?) the logging level of the app logger. Previously, myapp logger is set to 'DEBUG' level, whereas the corresponding handler is set to 'WARNING' level, so that no logger.debug(...) message is flushed to the console. Thanks!

Comment: Right. Think of your logging call as passing through two filters: the logger and the handler. Only calls at the same level or higher will get through.

This makes a little more sense if you consider that a logger might invoke multiple handlers, each with its own level.